# d3.js dynamic height change when uploaded to bl.ocks.org

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/johangithub/37e35b3a10a97c5ec42c) is my example derived from [example1](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025) and example2(bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/7022289).

My index.html is identical to example2, but I would like to incorporate dynamic expanding of the viewbox(window?) of example1 while maintaining the all the nodes collapsed as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the height of the svg on each update based on the number of nodes to display.

```
  //the height as per the number of nodes in the display.
  var height = Math.max(500, nodes.length * barHeight );

  d3.select("svg").transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .attr("height", height);
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzxkwdDJpZRNBb7su3Ao?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: he'll also have to expand the iFrame for bl.ocks.org, so something like `d3.select("iframe").style("height", height + 10);`

Comment: Mark, you were right, but the code above didn't work, so I added the following line and it worked.  `d3.select(self.frameElement).transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("height", height + "px");`